# How to check if input type="date" has value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date input and I am trying to check if has value or not, but the else condition is always displayed. How I can check if my date input has value?

```
<input name="bike_model_desc" class="date-theft" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" id="bike_acq_date_id" type="date" required>

$("#bike_acq_date_id").change(() => {
    if ($("#bike_acq_data_id").val()) {
        console.log("have value")
    } else {
        console.log("don't have value")
    }
})
```

Comment: Check for typos in your `if(){}` statement. Copy+Pasting is your friend, use it... or use `$(this)` so that you're not re-querying the DOM and creating typo pitfalls for yourself.

Comment: For some reason when I try to use $(this) is not working, I tried in a bunch of different elements.

Comment: My entire script is inside this `$(document).ready(function ()` and when I try to do a console.log($(this)) the log is `Object { 0: HTMLDocument http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/associate/new_proposal?brand=scott, length: 1 }`

Comment: There must be some nuance with arrow function expression scope. See https://jsfiddle.net/bxm1es0t/. You should stick to the jQuery doc syntax before trying to blaze your own trail. https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually  your id is `bike_acq_date_id` not `bike_acq_data_id`. But there is no need to use id to select `datepicker` value.

Use parameter of call back function of `change` event:`param.target.value`

```js
   $("#bike_acq_date_id").change((a) => {
            if (a.target.value) {
                console.log("have value",a.target.value)
            } else {
                console.log("don't have value")
            }
        })
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<input name="bike_model_desc" class="date-theft" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" id="bike_acq_date_id" type="date" required>
```